# How to remove Typescript support from Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

Adding TypeScript support in latest version of VS is easy - just add a TypeScript file and VS will automatically will reconfigure the project.

However when all TS files are gone it spits out this warning:

```
Warning: The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
```

It is possible to manually remove TypeScript support by editing the project file in notepad, but is there a GUI in VS that handles this?

Comment: Side note: Why on Earth would you use Notepad when you have Visual Studio??? Just `right-click | Unload Project`, then `right-click | Edit {project name here}`.

Comment: that's a neat hidden feature, thanks

Comment: Removed every element in the project file with "typescript" in it.  Seems to be the way to remove typescript.  No clue how it got there in the first place.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I removed TypeScript by hand.

1. Right-click on the Web-project file in the Solution Explorer and choose `Unload project`
2. Right-click again on the project file, and now choose `Edit {project-name}.csproj`
3. Remove all elements with the name `TypeScript` in it, and save the XML file
4. Right-click the project file, and choose `Reload project`

**Always keep a backup of the project file, as you may wreck it. Your millage may vary...**

Comment: Simple but helpful; thanks @doekman. I had to remove a ton of included tags for an Ember project I realized was crippling VS 2015. On step `3.` I removed thousands of lines of code, and now I get a clean build.  Using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to edit the Ember JS files now.

Comment: I know this is old, but I wanted to add to this helpful post one additional item in case anyone else is searching on this. I had to remove the following from my .csproj file:

<ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{4A0DDDB5-7A95-4FBF-97CC-616D07737A77}" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: A web project in visual studio 2017 does not have a csproj file to edit.

Comment: I have to do  this after adding every single typescript file as visual studio adds them back in. Is there anyway of disabling it permanently for a specific solution?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't UI for this.

Answer (score 2):

In the .csproj file commenting the entire line with Microsoft.TypeScript.targets is enough to disable the build.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use TypeScriptCompileBlocked tag under PropertyGroup tag of csproject file.

Yes in order to edit the csproj you need to open it in notepad or any other editor.
This property is not editable through visual studio.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This wont require you to remove any other typescript tag.

Comment: i did that and typescript warning still happening.