# Visual Studio Typescript intellisense applied to Javascript file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know how to stop this from happening? Sucks having

```
Function () { } //note: capital F
```

instead of

```
function(){ } //how its supposed to be
```

There is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690009/how-to-remove-typescript-support-from-visual-studio-project) asking if typescript can be removed.. the answer is no.

Would be awesome if someone knows the fix, or how to remove typescript (and all the other crap ..Windows Phone SDK..) from Visual Studio.